# merge two sparse matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, r-s4

I am quite new to recommender lab package and S4 classes, so please bear with me. 
The aim is to recommend Movies based on what the participants have rated on previous movies.

I trained the model using the Movie Lense dataset.

```
library(recommenderlab) 
Rec.model<-Recommender(MovieLense[1:400], method = "UBCF")
recommended.items.3 <- predict(Rec.model, MovieLense[500], n=10) #data from same dataset. 
top3 <- bestN(recommended.items.3, n = 3)
```

That is fine, but I want to create new participants who rated some movies from the Movie Lense dataset.

So how can I insert a new sparse matrix (new user[s]) that I just created into the Movie Lense dataset and then recommender movies based on what they have rated?

```
# new users
user <- factor(c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)))

# selected items
item <- c("Leave It to Beaver (1997)", "Saint, The (1997)",
"Casper (1995)","My Fellow Americans (1996)")

item.r<- sample(item)

#ratings
a<- sample(5,4)
b<- sample(5,4)

#insert into data frame
newUser <- data.frame(user=user, item = c(item,item.r),rating=c(a,b))

#convert to sparse format
sparse_ratings <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(newUser$user), 
                           j = as.numeric(newUser$item),
                           x = as.numeric(newUser$rating), 
                           dims = c(length(unique(newUser$user)),
                                 length(unique(newUser$item))),
                           dimnames = list(levels(newUser$user),       
                                       levels(newUser$item)))


new <- new("realRatingMatrix", data = sparse_ratings)

as(new[1],'list') #see list 
as(new[1],'matrix') # see matrix
as(new,'list')
str(new)

as(MovieLense[1],'matrix') #looks different
str(MovieLense) # look the same as str(new)


#How to combine MovieLense and new matrix together??
```